# Connecting Proxy server of one laptop with other laptop in Windows 7

Tags: wireless-networking, proxy, wireless-router, squid, proxy-server

I have two laptops at home. I connect to the net using wifi router in both.

On one I have installed Squid Proxy server. And I have verified that it is working.

On the other, how do I ensure that it connects to this proxy server instead of the wifi router directly?

Both laptops run Win 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your wireless router, you can set a rule to block outbound HTTP traffic from everything except the proxy server.

Comment: But how will I connect that laptop with the one having proxy server?

Comment: Within your browser settings, set it to use the Squid server.  As a COMPLETE self-serving move, if you want to add adblocking to the proxy server, I wrote an article on how to do it a few years ago: http://www.ozmonet.com/projects/adblock.html